# Mocking repository for unit testing in NestJS using Jest

Tags: jestjs, nestjs

I have a test class that's responsible for testing an API endpoint that inserts data into a database. During testing, I want to avoid actual database operations and instead mock the repository.

In my repository, I have two methods: one that returns a value and another that doesn't return anything. Below is my testing code:

```js
describe('MyController', () => {
  let app;
  let module: TestingModule;
  let repository: MyRepository;
  const mockS3 = {
    listObjectsV2: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  };

  const mockS3Provider = {
    provide: 'AWS.S3',
    useValue: mockS3,
  };

  jest.mock('../dataAccess/my.repository', () => ({
    MockMyRepository: jest.fn(() => ({
      createData: jest.fn((item, item1) => {}),
      checkData: jest.fn((item, base) => {}),
    })),
  }));

  beforeAll(async () => {
    module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
      controllers: [MyController],
      providers: [MyRepository, MyService, mockS3Provider],
    }).compile();

    app = module.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();
    repository = module.get<MyRepository>(MyRepository);
  });

  afterEach(async () => {
    await app.close();
  });

  it('should test the /addData endpoint', async () => {
    mockS3.listObjectsV2.mockResolvedValue({});
    jest
      .spyOn(MockMyRepository.prototype, 'checkData')
      .mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve());
    jest
      .spyOn(MockMyRepository.prototype, 'createData')
      .mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve());

    const requestBody = {};

    const response = await request(app.getHttpServer())
      .post('/data/addData')
      .send(requestBody);

    const expected1t = {};
    const expected2 = {};

    expect(MockMyRepository.prototype.checkTenantAccess).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      requestBody,
      expected1t
    );
    expect(MockMyRepository.prototype.createBucketTenant).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(response.body).toEqual({ isAllowed: true });
    expect(mockS3.listObjectsV2).toHaveBeenCalledWith(/* expected arguments */);
  });
});
```

However, when I run the test, I'm encountering the following error:

```
● MyController › should test the /addData endpoint

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

    Number of calls: 0

    86 | expect(MockMyRepository.prototype.checkData).toHaveBeenCalledWith(requestBody, expected1t)
       | ^
```

I have cross-verified the imports and method arguments. They are correct. I have also followed the links to similar questions and guides on mocking with Jest.

Why is my `jest.mock` setup for repository mocking not working as expected?